# Read current opened message thread in Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This set of Apps Script lines:

```
 var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox

 var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
```

helps in getting the first message of the first thread.

**'Any method to query data from the current mail which a user has opened?'**

Say for example:

```
var message = GmailApp.*getCurrentThread*.getCurrentMessage();
```

Need this to parse data for only specific messages and save it in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Comment: I did, there is no way to read the current opened message. Probably my best shot would be to get the message by its id using getMessagebyId(id) function. But that would again not allow me log the details in 1-click.

Answer (score 1):

```
var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
var thread = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getThread();
```

This returns GmailThread object. You can use the methods to get threadId, messageSubject, messages, labels and other stuffs as specified in [the gmail-thread docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread).